# Creating a dictionary of dictionaries (or a tuple?) from CSV in Python

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, tuples

I'm looking to read a CSV file and create an object in Python to store a large data set. The data is in a CSV file (with headers) and the first two entries in every row represent X,Y coordinates. Later on in the program, I will be sorting and performing operations on the data for each X,Y coordinate.

Here's sample data:

```
x, y, field1, field2, field3
1, 2, 10, 20, 30
1, 2, 20, 30 40
7, 4, 2, 49, 39
```

I think the object I want to create from this looks like this:

Position, values

```
(1,2) => {field1=10,field2=20,field3=30},{field1=20,field2=30,field3=40}
(7,4) => {field1=2,field2=49,field3=39}
```

Is this a dictionary inside a dictionary with a key of a tuple? I've been scouring the internet for an example of this and am having trouble finding it. Does handling the data in this way make sense?

So far I've been trying to start by just getting the data into one dictionary but I'm having trouble with that. The code below only prints the headers:

```
import csv
import sys

dict={}

with open('data.csv') as file:
    data = csv.reader(file)
    headers = next(data)[0:]
    length = len(headers)
    for row in data:
        for i in range(length):
            dict[headers[i]]=row[i]

for x in dict:
    print x
```

Comment: What you have is going to be a dictionary with a list of dicts.  For example `{(1,2):[{'field1':10,'field2':20},{'field1':20,'field2':30}], {(7,4):[{'field1':2,'field2':49}]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your csv structure is known and fixed:

```
import csv
import sys
from collections import defaultdict

HEADERS = ["x", "y", "field1", "field2", "field3"]

def read_data(source):
    data = defaultdict(list)
    reader = csv.DictReader(source, fieldnames=HEADERS)
    next(reader) # skip headers
    for row in reader:
        # this will at once build the key tuple
        # and remove the "x" and "y" keys from the 
        # row dict
        key = row.pop("x"), row.pop("y")
        data[key].append(row)
    return data

with open('data.csv') as source:
    data = read_data(source)

print data
```

As a side note: don't use `dict` or `file` as var names, specially at the top level, as it will shadow the builtin `dict` and `file` types.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, I changed my variable names accordingly!

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv

# let's create a class to hold the data in each line
class Capsule:
    def __init__(x,y,f1,f2,f3):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.field1 = f1
        self.field2 = f2
        self.field3 = f3

# let's read the file
with open('/path/to/file') as infile:
    infile.readline()
    capsules = []
    for x, y, f1, f2, f3 in csv.reader(infile):
        capsules.append(Capsule(x,y,f1,f2,f3))


# done reading all data
# let's sort the list by x,y coordinates
capsules.sort(key=lambda c : (c.x, c.y))
```

This usage of a list helps sort things, etc. However, if you are interested in knowing what object/s is at a specific set of coordinates, then you're better off with a dictionary:

```
with open('/path/to/file') as infile:
    infile.readline()
    capsules = {}
    for x, y, f1, f2, f3 in csv.reader(infile):
        if (x,y) not in capsules:
            capsules[(x,y)] = []
        capsules[(x,y)].append(Capsule(x,y,f1,f2,f3))

# sort by x,y coordinates:
sortedCapsules = [capsules[k] for k in sorted(capsules)]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this code will help

```
import csv
import sys

with open('data.csv') as file:
    data = csv.reader(file)
    headers = next(data)[0:]
    length = len(headers)

    res = dict()
    for row in data:

        fields = dict()
        for i in range(2,length):
            fields[headers[i]]=int(row[i])
        res[(int(row[0]),int(row[1]))] = fields

for x in res:
    print x,res[x]
```